# For three i.i.d continuous random variables, exactly one is the minimum, almost surely

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables

> Show that for i.i.d. continuous r.v.s X, Y, Z,
>   $$P (X < min(Y, Z)) + P (Y < min(X, Z)) + P (Z < min(X, Y )) = 1.$$

Intuitively, it is clear that the probability that any of the three is the smallest equals one. I would argue that by symmetry,

$$P (X < min(Y, Z)) + P (Y < min(X, Z)) + P (Z < min(X, Y )) = 3P (X < min(Y, Z)).$$
and $P(X < min(Y, Z))= P(X \text{ is the smallest of the three}) = 1/3$. But how to do that more formally?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These three events are disjoint and their union is the event that there is no tie. Now, it is a classical fact (asked and solved *many* times on the site) that, if some random variables $U$ and $V$ are independent with continuous distributions, then $P(U=V)=0$ (actually, one of the distributions being continuous suffices). Thus, the probability of a tie is at most the sum of $P(X=Y)$, $P(Y=Z)$ and $P(X=Z)$, which are all $0$.

Comment: Thank's, that gave me to think about.

Comment: $$\bbox[7pt,border:3px #FF69B4 solid]{\color{red}{\large  >200\mathbb K.\;\text{Congrats!!}}}$$

Comment: @Venus Thanks. (How did you manage to post this 14 seconds after the exact moment when the rep crossed the line?)

Comment: You might say that I'm watching your activities here recently & I upvote this one just for completing your great achievement here. You deserve it.

Comment: @Venus In principle I disagree with votes that are not strictly related to the content of the post but I guess that making an exception in this case cannot seriously hurt... :-) Thanks anyway.

Comment: @Did So congrats from my side!

Comment: Congratulations @Did ! thanks for your 
6,347 Answers ! =)

Comment: Congratulations @Did. Btw, is merely disjoint sufficient? Not pairwise disjoint not needed? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Measure_%28mathematics%29#Definition

Comment: @BCLC No. Obvious counterexamples.

Comment: @Did um, needed or not needed?